# React: Updating state in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I believe this is fairly straightforward but for some reason I'm not able to find the answers after quite abit of google :/

I have a simple component below that fetches some data from my spring boot app and converts it into a JSON promise.

1. I'm not sure if I am allowed to set the state using the promise, or do I have to parse it through another method before I do so? The state of `visitDetails` remains empty after `setVisitDetails` is called.
2. How do I use the map function to reference the variables that are in the response?

**Component**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const QrCodeDisplay = () => {
  
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const qrId = urlParams.get('qrCode');
    const fetchQrURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/qr-code/'+qrId;
    const [visitDetails, setVisitDetails] = useState([]);
    const fetchVisitURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/visit-by-qrcodeid/'+qrId;

    useEffect(()=> {

       
        console.log(fetchVisitURL);
        
        const fetchVisitDetail = async () => {
            try{
                const res = await fetch(fetchVisitURL,{
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                });
                const jsonResponse = res.json();
                console.log(jsonResponse);
                setVisitDetails(jsonResponse);
                
            
            }catch(error){
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        };
        fetchVisitDetail();
        
    },[fetchVisitURL]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Your QR entry pass</h2>
            <h3>Start Date of Visit:</h3>
            <img src={fetchQrURL} alt="QR entry" width="200px" height="200px"></img>
        </div>
    )
}

export default QrCodeDisplay
```

JSON from backend (API works via Postman and React component returns promise as success)

```
[
    {
        "scheduledVisitId": 1,
        "visitorId": 2,
        "startDateOfVisit": "2021-01-18",
        "endDateOfVisit": "2021-01-19",
        "qrCodeId": "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
        "valid": true,
        "oneTimeUse": false,
        "raisedBy": 123456
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to await `res.json()` because `.json()` method also returns a promise. Awaiting `res.json()` will give you the requested data.

Comment: Thanks very much! It solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed await before res.json()

````
    useEffect(()=> {

       
        console.log(fetchVisitURL);
        
        const fetchVisitDetail = async () => {
            try{
                const res = await fetch(fetchVisitURL,{
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                });
                const jsonResponse = await res.json();
                console.log(jsonResponse);
                setVisitDetails(jsonResponse);
                
            
            }catch(error){
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        };
        fetchVisitDetail();
        
    },[fetchVisitURL]);
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks very much! Marked this as answered.